# Scilab, calculate average of part of vector (Matrix column)

Tags: scilab

matrix data with two columns have time (1st column) and angle (2nd column) information stored. I need to calculate the average of the angle information between 5000 and 13000.
Problem, 5000 and 13000 doesn't exist as exact values in the 1st column.

I tried to find the index in the x-value vector for given points but I fail always on the problem not having the exact search value in the matrix 1st column.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean indexing, e.g.

```
k = data(:,1) >= 5000 & data(:,1) <= 13000 
avg = mean(data(k,:))
```

Comment: Hello Stéphane, thank you. Does it mean that I can use a vector `k` to address a range in the matrix?

Comment: Yeah. Here k is a  boolean (true=selected, false=unselected). It can also be a vector of valid indices w.r.t. to the corresponding dimension of the matrix.